# Can I see all locations that a DMG file install files to?

Tags: dmg

I wonder if there is a way to sort of "unroll" a dmg file and reveal which directories it will install files to?

Comment: DMG's don't install anywhere, are you thinking of PKG's?

Comment: i don't know man? am I? I just want to see all locations where files are put when I install a program using a DMG

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind when you say "install"? Running a pkg file from within the dmg file, or copying a .app bundle from a dmg file into your applications folder?

Answer (score 6):

A DMG (Disk Image) file is like a zip file.
It's compressed and has a check built-in to check if the integrity of the app is intact.
Once you open a DMG file, in most cases, you just have to drag/drop the application into you Applications folder and that's it.
If you want to see the full content of that application, go to
Applications folder
Right click on an app
Select 'Show the ... content'
In the 'Contents' directory, you'll see all dirs and files that came with your app.
I don't know if that's the answer your are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

DMG refers to a Disk Image. When you open a DMG, nothing happens–it's like opening a folder (effectively, there are some differences but none that affect the answer to this question).

Typically, you're asked to drag the application to the Applications folder. This is exactly as it appears–the file you're dragging (the application) is being copied to the Applications folder.

Sometimes, you're asked to open an installer. The specifics of how the installer works varies based on how the developer wrote it. The DMG portion of the process doesn't really effect that.

The standard is a PKG file, which opens the standard installer program. This has you go through a few steps, with an outline on the left side of the screen. These files *can* be analyzed. I've found an article online (but have not tested it) [here](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-inspect-an-os-x-package-file-pkg-without-installing).

Comment: No the standard is dmg  - Very few programs use a .pkg installer

Comment: @Mark A DMG is *just a container*. It's essentially a way to wrap up files for transportation and storage. Sort of the computer equivalent of a cardboard box. They can contain pretty much anything, and PKG is one fairly common way to install software that's often wrapped in a DMG for safe transport. Go to [support.apple.com/downloads](https://support.apple.com/downloads), and look at pretty much any of the macOS software -- they're mostly PKG-wrapped-in-DMG files.

Comment: Most of the apps I see are just the app and installed by copy

Comment: @Mark A DMG may be a standard for packaging applications, but it's not an installer. A PKG file is the standard for any installation process. Most apps don't need that, but the question asked about installation and so I referenced a PKG.